# Problem with authorize view in BigQuery: Dataset access entries is empty

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to authorize a view programmatically in BigQuery and I have the following issue: I just tried the code proposed in the Google docs (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) but when it comes the part of getting the current access entries for the dataset the result is always empty. I don't want to overwrite the current configuration. Any idea about this behavior?

```
def authorize_view(dataset_id, view_name):
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    view_ref = dataset_ref.table(view_name)
    source_dataset = bigquery.Dataset(client.dataset('mydataset'))
    access_entries = source_dataset.access_entries  # This returns []
    access_entries.append(
        bigquery.AccessEntry(None, 'view', view_ref.to_api_repr())
    )
    source_dataset.access_entries = access_entries
    source_dataset = client.update_dataset(
        source_dataset, ['access_entries'])  # API request
```

Comment: What should this function be doing? The code proposed in that link takes a dataset and a member (for instance using its e-mail) and grants certain permissions to it. You can get the access_entries in "dataset_ref" (by calling dataset_ref.access_entries), what is source_dataset object supposed to be?

Comment: `source_dataset` is the bigquery reference to the dataset and `access_entries` should return the list of the actual access rules for that dataset.

Comment: you can get the access_entries of a dataset with dataset_id by doing: [dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_id), access_entries = dataset.access_entries]. why are you defining two datasets and why one has variable dataset_id and the other pure text 'dataset_id' and why aren't you calling any of them as stated in the documentation?

Comment: in addition, what is the main purpose of this function? it looks like you were trying to give permissions on a particular view (docs state that cannot be done)